# Thinkpad X260 ubuntu keyboard backlight not working 20.04

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, bios, keyboard-backlight

I have a Thinkpad X260 running Ubunto 20.04. I just replaced my non-backlight keyboard for one with a backlight and the backlight does not light. All other functions of the keyboard work fine.

Fn+spacebar makes the system act as if it is controlling the backlight (the backlight icon appears on the screen and under options-power the backlight slide bar is shown and moves) but the backlight does not come on.

When in BIOS the Fn green light illuminates and the red mute and microphone mute lights on the function keys light up but not the full backlight.

`echo 2|sudo tee /sys/class/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness` changes the apparent setting, which corresponds with the setting shown under options, so kbd_backlight is present at that path.

Is there anything I can do to enable the light? Is it possible the keyboard itself is dodgy?

I've updated the BIOS from 1.46 R02ET73W (2020-01-08) to 1.50 R02ET77W (2023-01-18) with no improvement.

`sudo lshw -short` gives the output:

```
H/W path         Device     Class          Description

                            system         20F5S6EH00 (LENOVO_MT_20F5_BU_Think_F
/0                          bus            20F5S6EH00
/0/3                        memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/4                        memory         64KiB L1 cache
/0/5                        memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/6                        memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/7                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50
/0/8                        memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/8/0                      memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MH
/0/b                        memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/100                      bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Co
/0/100/2                    display        Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
/0/100/14                   bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Control
/0/100/14/0      usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/8               multimedia     Integrated Camera
/0/100/14/1      usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                 generic        Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
/0/100/16                   communication  Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                   storage        Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHC
/0/100/1c                   bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Por
/0/100/1c/0                 generic        RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.2                 bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Por
/0/100/1c.2/0    wlp4s0     network        Wireless 8260
/0/100/1f                   bridge         Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                 memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                 multimedia     Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                 bus            Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
/0/100/1f.6      enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection I219-V
/0/0                        system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/1                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                        system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/9                        generic        PnP device LEN0071
/0/a                        generic        PnP device LEN2014
/0/c                        generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/d                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/e                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/f                        system         PnP device PNP0c31
/0/10            scsi1      storage        
/0/10/0.0.0      /dev/sda   disk           250GB CT250MX500SSD1
/0/10/0.0.0/1               volume         512MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/10/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2  volume         232GiB Extended partition
/0/10/0.0.0/2/5  /dev/sda5  volume         232GiB EXT4 volume
/1                          power          45N1113
/2                          power          45N1738
```

[command output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvZYU.png)